# Don`t work synchronization via svn in wso2 api manager

Tags: svn, wso2

I created svn-repository: `# svnadmin create apigw,`

Repository is available, and API manager was created one empty directory in repository.

```
# svn co svn://repo-server/apigw
A    apigw/-1234
Checked out revision 1.

# ll /opt/wso2am/repository/components/lib/trilead_ssh2_1.0.0_build215_1.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 227983 фев 21 17:41
/opt/wso2am/repository/components/lib/trilead_ssh2_1.0.0_build215_1.0.0.jar

# ll /opt/wso2am/repository/components/dropins/svnkit-bundle-1.0.0.jar 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2954568 фев 24 15:23
opt/wso2am/repository/components/dropins/svnkit-bundle-1.0.0.jar
```

But synchronization doesn't work. There are some errors in `wso2carbon.log`:

> TID: [0] [AM] [2014-02-24 16:21:44,104] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask} -  Deployment synchronization commit for tenant -1234 failed
>
> {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask}
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.DeploymentSynchronizerException: Error while committing artifacts to the SVN repository
>           at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.commit(DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.java:116)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.deploymentSyncCommit(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:173)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:114)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.DeploymentSynchronizerException: Error while committing artifacts to the SVN repository
>           at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.handleException(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:744)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.commit(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:365)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizer.commit(DeploymentSynchronizer.java:145)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.commit(DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.java:114)
>           ... 9 more
>
> Caused by: org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientException: org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: '/opt/wso2am/repository/deployment/server' is not a working copy
>           at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.cleanup(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2069)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.commit(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:339)
>           ... 11 more
>
> Caused by: org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: '/opt/wso2am/repository/deployment/server' is not a working copy
>           at org.tigris.subversion.javahl.JavaHLObjectFactory.throwException(JavaHLObjectFactory.java:777)
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.throwException(SVNClientImpl.java:1850)
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.cleanup(SVNClientImpl.java:863)
>           at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.cleanup(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2066)
>           ... 12 more
>
> Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: '/opt/wso2am/repository/deployment/server' is not a working copy
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.open(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:163)
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.doOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:364)
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:272)
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:265)
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doCleanup(SVNWCClient.java:521)
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doCleanup(SVNWCClient.java:480)
>           at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.cleanup(SVNClientImpl.java:861)

Comment: Are you trying extract a new copy of APIM and pointing to old SVN repo? There are conflicts with the file in repo and in the pack I think. Better delete all the files inside 'wso2am/repository/deployment/server' in the worker nodes and try.

Comment: No. I was created new SVN repo and new installation of APIM. I was modified other configs APIM not in directory.

Comment: I think this is maybe problem with a version of svn. for example my native svn client don`t work with wso2 svn repo.
# svn cleanup 
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '/opt/wso2am-1.5.0/repository/deployment/server' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
What version of svn server is guarantee work?

Comment: WSO2 SVN-based Deployment Synchronizer don`t working with subversion-1.7.13 and working with subversion-1.6.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 SVN-based Deployment Synchronizer don`t working with subversion-1.7.13 and working with subversion-1.6.11, if you using java-libs svnkit-bundle.
But it working via native system subversion 1.7.*